# Search data object and concatenate items in array of strings

Tags: python

I have a data structure that looks like this:

```
[{u'id': [u'213938162d125653628e0912986e78b23d359ca3'], u'items': [u'item1', u'item12'], u'version': u'v1'},
 {u'id': [u'213938162d125653628e0912986e78b23d359ca3'], u'items': [u'item1', u'item2', u'item3', u'item4'], u'version': u'v2'},
 {u'id': [u'213938162d125653628e0912986e78b23d359ca3'], u'items': [u'item1', u'item2'], u'version': u'v3'},
 {u'id': [u'213938162d125653628e0912986e78b23d359ca3'], u'items': [u'item1'], u'version': u'v4'}
]
```

I need a function that can search based on the value of the "version" to get the "items" and and then concatenate the items into a single string.

What would be the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def joinItems(myList, version)
    toConcate = []
    for dct in filter(lambda dct: dct[u"version"] == version, myList):
       toConcate.extend(dct[u"items"])

    return "seperator".join(toConcate)
```

It's also possible to do this within a single generator comprehension:

```
return "sep".join(itertools.chain(dct[u"items"] for dct in myList if dct[u"version"] == version))
```

Comment: Thanks, Is this python 2 or 3?

Comment: This should run on both 2 and 3.